# $L_1$ convergence rates for multivariate kernel density estimation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, st.statistics, kernels, learning-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable on $\mathbb R^d$ with probability density function $f$, and let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ of $X$ be $n$ iid copies of $X$. Given a bandwidth parameter $h=h_n > 0$ and a kernel $K:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (e.g Gaussian kernel $K(z):= e^{-z^2/2}/\sqrt{2\pi}$), consider the following kernel density estimator (KDE) for $f$

$$
\hat{f}_{n,h}(x) := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h^{-d}K\left(\frac{\|x -X_i\|_2}{h}\right).
$$

> **Question.** *Under what minimal conditions on $f$ (e.g smoothness, etc.) and perhaps $K$ do we have an estimate of the form $\mathbb E \|\hat{f}_{n,h}-f\|_{L^1} := \mathbb E_S\, \int_{\mathbb R^d}|\hat{f}_{n,h}(x)-f(x)|\, dx \lesssim n^{-\beta} $ for some $\beta>0$ independent of $n$ ?*